# country with the highest number of tests(oracle plsql)

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

**Data Model:**
[image: 1]

Hi, I am trying to get "country with the highest number of tests".

**Query:**
[image: 2]

I tried using one table.. ok... but how I get it with "countryname"?  How should I make this with inner join?

Comment: just as an aside, simply adding an underscore to "DATE"  (DATE_) to keep from using a reserved word is not, in my opinion, a very good naming convention.  I look to name all of my columns as adjective_noun.  Much more descriptive/self-documenting, and no chance of trying to use a reserved or key word.  I'd also think that an individual test would have enough properties to justify having it's own TESTS table with a unique row for each unique test.  And with that, storing 'total_tests' is a design flaw, as it would be derived from the TESTS table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join, as you said.

```
select s.countryname,
       s.date_,
       s.total_tests
from (select 
         row_number() over (order by a.total_tests desc) rn,
         a.date_,
         a.total_tests,
         c.countryname
      from cases_by_countries a join country c 
        on c.countryid = a.country_id       
     ) s
where s.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

if you need only the highest you should try this

```
select c.CountryID, ts.Total_Tests
from Country c
    inner join (
    select top(1) Country_ID, Total_Tests
    from CASES_BY_COUNTRIES
    order by Total_Tests desc
) ts on c.CountryID = ts.Country_ID
```

Comment: "top" command is used in mssql.. maybe it work.. thanks